# I've got the warning of "Preload key requests" from page speed insights and can not resolve the issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, frontend, pagespeed, lighthouse

I am working on web page optimization using google page speed insights.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&url=https%3A%2F%2Fthaniya-japan.com%2F

My website
https://thaniya-japan.com/

---

Google says "Preload key requests" even after I preloaded the specified .woff font file.

[google says "Preload key requests"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MeaO.png)

---

I had already added the rel="preload" to the .woff file to fix that like below.

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" id="preload_dpicons_woff-css" href="https://thaniya-japan.com/wp-content/themes/dp-fresco/css/fonts/dpicons.woff" media="all">
```

---

the .woff files were originally loaded in some .css files like below

```
@font-face{
font-family:"dpicons";
src:url('fonts/dpicons.woff') format('woff'),url('fonts/dpicons.ttf') format('truetype')
}
```

Actually I also commented out the @font-face part in those .css files to eliminate preload warning from page speed insights.

But page speed insights is still saying "Preload key requests".

---

Does anyone know what is happening and how I can eliminate the warning of "Preload key requests" from the page speed insights?

---

By the way , below is the way I added the .woff file to make it preloaded.

```
function custom_enqueue_scripts_early() {
    wp_enqueue_style('preload_dpicons_woff', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts/dpicons.woff', array("dashicons"), null);
    wp_enqueue_style('preload_dpicons_ttf', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts/dpicons.ttf', array("dashicons"), null);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts_early' ,5);


add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'my_style_loader_tag_filter', 10, 2);

function my_style_loader_tag_filter($html, $handle) {

    $font = "";
    if($handle === 'preload_dpicons_woff'){
        $font = " type='font/woff' ";
    }elseif($handle === 'preload_dpicons_ttf'){
        $font = " type='font/ttf' ";
    }

    $replaced = "rel='preload' as='font' ".$font." crossorigin='anonymous'";

    if(strpos($handle,'preload_dpicons') !== false){
        return str_replace("rel='stylesheet'",$replaced , $html);
    }
  
  return $html;

}
```

Comment: This is a very wide topic... Google insights is also not a very good tool for performance diagnostics. If you want to have something more accurate try: gtmetrix.com

Comment: But Google use their own algorithms to rank search results. I am trying to work out how to  'preload' fonts called using font-face as suggested by Google. Is adding a preload link the the <head> enough? Does the css @fontface need to be edited? If it is commented out, how can the css know what font-family name is and be used elsewhere in the stylesheet?